# How to share domain objects in highly distributed application using maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Scenario : The application XApp that i am working on is a large application with some 15 micro-applications distributed among several servers.These micro-applications are maintained by multiple teams. These applications communicate with each other mostly using RESTful Api and have common json contracts for domain objects.

Problem : since we are going for major revamping, even for a small change like adding a field in one domain object for a micro-application we are required to make changes in all other micro-applications and each application has to undergo testing cycle.

Expectation : Have Shared domain objects

I am considering maven/jenkins as a solution, by any means can we create a multi-module build with each micro-application deployed as a child web-project (.war) that inherits the domain module (.jar) as a dependency. And then use jenkins for distributed deployment of child project. If it works this will ensure shared domain layer as it should be.Is it possible ?

Secondly are there any other solutions for shared domain objects amongst micro-services?